# Debug Yii console application in PHPStorm

Tags: yii, phpstorm

PHPStrom is a great IDE. I really like it. But I bumped into an issue. I can't find instructions how to configure debugging for Yii console application. 
I set debugging for Yii web application and it works fine.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Upd1**: Actually I figured out that there are 3 cases of the Yii console application.

Standard Yii console application (command files in the protected/commands folder of the webapp)

Standalone Yii console application (independent console aaplication without web application)

**[My case]** YiiBooster console application (YiiBooster has advanced, but good structure for medium or big projects)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some period of time I found the solution. In my case it must be split in 2 parts:

### Configure XDebug in PHPStorm

1. Get appropriate Xdebug version. [Use this wizard from official xdebug site](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php); *just copy&past your phpinfo() response into window and it will tell you which version you must download*.
2. Install it and make sure that XDebug is activated (***phpinfo()* must return xdebug section in the response**). [Use the following link for detailed instructions](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide)
   [image]
3. Set XDebug as debugger for PHP in Project Settings
   [image]

**[The steps below are specific for Yii console application debugging]**

4. Find *yiic.php* file in your project and Run or Debug it first time. 
   [image]
5. After this go Run->Edit Config and set name of your command in the arguments with required parameters.
   [image]
6. Now set breakpoints in your code and activate "Listen debugger connections” button.
   [image]

### Debugging Yii command actions

1. If you want **to use actions (like actionRebuildIndexes) in the command it needs to call the parent::run** method in the run() function.

   public function run($args) {
       parent::run($args);
       return 0;
   }
2. For debugging it needs to specify the action name in the arguments for yiic.php Run Configuration (see image above)

Answer (score 1):

[There is article in jetbrains blog about it.](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/10/debug-command-line-scripts-with-phpstorm-2-1/)

Answer (score 0):

you just set your php.ini and add an parameter in [xdebug](/questions/tagged/xdebug) like this:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

then you can debug your console application.